# Chrome sound not working on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: google-chrome, 15.04

I just got ubuntu and all I wanted to use chrome for is netflix but the sound doesn't work. The sound works on every other app on my laptop except chrome. Even the sound on chromium works. I've tried installing the flash player plugin but it was already on there. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall alsa and pulseaudio

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Then restart Chrome